# Why I cannot edit the navigation bar with a navigation controller embedded?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

[image]

In this simple example, I try to embed the root controller with a navigation controller. But when I try to change the content in the navigation controller's navigation bar, XCode doesn't allow me to do that. Why?

And if the root controller is embedded with a navigation controller, should I set the navigation controller to the new root controller?

Comment: your initial VC is not Navigationcontroller, your initial VC is your center VC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can drag drop NavigationItem to your view controller and change it title, ...

2) Yes, you should. :)